# SQL Server JDBC getLine getSeverity

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Is there anyway I can get the: Line, Level, State
From a SQLException when using a microsoft JDBC driver?

Below is a error message from isql or similar tool

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

The Java SQLException only has: ex.getErrorCode(), ex.getMessage(), ex.getSQLState() and toString()
But none of the above methods displays "Line", "Level", "State"

I would like something similar to Sybase jConnect, where you can do:

```
    if (sqlex instanceof EedInfo) // Message from jConnect
    {
        EedInfo eedi = (EedInfo) sqlex;

        int msgNum       = sqlex.getErrorCode();
        int severity     = eedi.getSeverity();
        int state        = eedi.getState(); 
        int lineNumber   = eedi.getLineNumber();
        String procName  = eedi.getProcedureName();
        String srvName   = eedi.getServerName();
    }
```

Or just get a string with the "Line, Level, State", then I could parse the string the get the Line number of the error origin.

BTW: can you downgrade a SQLException into a SQLWarning in MSSQL JDBC driver
This how you would do it in Sybase jConnect

```
    if (conn instanceof SybConnection)
    {
        ((SybConnection)conn).setSybMessageHandler(new SybMessageHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public SQLException messageHandler(SQLException sqlex)
            {
                // if here you can filter out specific error messages...
                if (sqlex.getErrorCode() == 9999)
                    return null;

                // or Downgrade messages to SQLWarnings, so executions wont be interrupted.
                return AseConnectionUtils.sqlExceptionToWarning(sqlex);
            }
        });
    }
```